# How can I access the frames captured by Camera from the video buffer in Android 4.1

Tags: android-ndk

I wondering if I can do that in Android space.

The version I am using is Android 4.1

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think you can use the JNI and if you know what classes to use you can get the buffer you ask for.

Try chewing on the 2 links: [here](http://video.linux.com/videos/exposing-the-android-camera-stack) and [here](http://marakana.com/static/courseware/android/Aptina-Android-Camera-Internals.pdf)

Note that before ICS, the stack is very different from what is presented in these 2 links. So, what you come up with for ICS wont work on 2.3.3 or on 3.x.x.